# Differences in observer class naming?

Tags: magento-1, event-observer, best-practice

When creating an observer you add your `model` to config.xml like ...

```
<models>
    <some_name>
        <class>My_Module_Model</class>
    </some_name>
</models>
```

When adding the event part you can do this

```
<observers>
    <some_alias>
        <class>some_name/observer</class>
        <method>someMethod</method>
    </some_alias>
</observers>
```

Or use full class name like

```
<observers>
    <some_alias>
        <class>My_Module_Model_Observer</class>
        <method>someMethod</method>
    </some_alias>
</observers>
```

Whats the difference and why should I prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Sohel Rana, for pointing to `$this->getGroupedClassName('model', $modelClass);`

**This makes the difference.**

Most important lines for this question are:

```
// First - check maybe the entity class was rewritten
$className = null;
if (isset($config->rewrite->$class)) {
    $className = (string)$config->rewrite->$class;
} else {
```

If using full class name, rewrites of the related model have no effect. It will load the class that is declared. If using `some_name/observer` you can rewrite `Some_Modules_Model_Observer` and the new class is used. *Think  it's better to use second approach.*

Comment: Absolutely. You can still rewrite observers in both cases by overriding `observers/some_alias/class` in `config.xml` of an own module that depends on the original one. But it's better to keep the possibility to rewrite the observer class itself.

Answer (score 1):

There are no big difference when Magento create an object of class tag. Open
**app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php**

```
/**
 * Retrieve module class name
 *
 * @param   sting $modelClass
 * @return  string
 */
public function getModelClassName($modelClass)
{
    $modelClass = trim($modelClass);
    if (strpos($modelClass, '/')===false) {
        return $modelClass;
    }
    return $this->getGroupedClassName('model', $modelClass);
}
```

Check line `if (strpos($modelClass, '/')===false) {`

If you pass `My_Module_Model_Observer` type of name then magento return this without anything.

If you pass `some_name/observer` then `return $this->getGroupedClassName('model', $modelClass);` this code create a actual class and return.

So both ways are acceptable and magento standard.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to `getGroupedClassName()` :)