# Observer problem failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

My Observer file is actually in the **local code pool** but it tries to open it from **Warning:** include(**Mage**/Schott/CurrencyDetector/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory. I don't know why it is trying to open the file from the wrong path.

Caches and compiler are disabled. Here is my **config.xml**. Can anyone help? Thanks!

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Schott_CurrencyDetector>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Schott_CurrencyDetector>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <schott_currencydetector>
            <class>Schott_CurrencyDetector_Model</class>
        </schott_currencydetector>
    </models>
</global>
<frontend>
    <events>
        <customer_login>
            <observers>
                <Schott_CurrencyDetector_Observer>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>Schott_CurrencyDetector/observer</class>
                    <method>customerLogin</method>
                </Schott_CurrencyDetector_Observer>
            </observers>
        </customer_login>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error pops up, because the class you try to use is not declared, so Magento "thinks" it's a part of `code/core/Mage/`.

Try to change:

```
<class>Schott_CurrencyDetector/observer</class>
```

to

```
<class>schott_currencydetector/observer</class>
```

---

It has to match the model alias you have defined here:

```
<models>
    <schott_currencydetector>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in your `config.xml`

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <customer_login>
            <observers>
                <Schott_CurrencyDetector_Observer>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>Schott_CurrencyDetector_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>customerLogin</method>
                </Schott_CurrencyDetector_Observer>
            </observers>
        </customer_login>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Note : remember  that you can create observer in `app->code->local->Schott->CurrencyDetector->Model->Observer.php`

Comment: Just to mention ... https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186032/differences-in-observer-class-naming. So i think it's not good using full class names.

Comment: It is another way to implement observer.